# How to select all tags with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Consider:

```html
<a title="Citrate of Magnesia for Consumers" href="/cdi/citrate-of-magnesia-solution.html">
<b>Citrate of Magnesia</b>
```

I'm trying to pull data from a medication website, and how do I select all the text in the `<b></b>` tags?

Because that's the text I want.

I've tried `*//a[@b]`, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to rely on the preceding `a` element, use [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling), example:

```
//a/following-sibling::b
```

Python code:

```
b = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/following-sibling::b")
print(b.text)
```

If you want multiple `b` tags having `a` as a preceding element:

```
for b in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a/following-sibling::b"):
    print(b.text)
```

---

Solution provided after chatting:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.drugs.com/drug-class/laxatives.html?condition_id=&generic=0&sort=rating&order=desc")

# Wait for the table list to load
table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.data-list")))

for b in table.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr td > a[href] > b"):
    print(b.text)
```

Comment: waits thats what I type in my xpath?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez I've added an example python code. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. will this pull out the text in it though? or wll it just locate the <b></b> tags?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez updated the code with a sample of code to get the text

Comment: thanks a lot this. xpath things is pretty confusing.

care to point me in the right direction to learn it better?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez there are plenty of xpath tutorials on the web, but don't forget to practice using, for example, a chrome dev console and `$x()` function. There are several key notations and functions that you would widely use while trying to locate elements on a page.

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez note that I personally don't like `//a/following-sibling::b` expression as it looks too broad for me. If you would provide more markup, we can probably make a better expression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77552/discussion-between-halcyon-abraham-ramirez-and-alecxe).